# How to copy a file onto another while preserving the latter's text

Tags: python, file, copy, shutil

Basically if we have a temp1.txt with text 'qwertyuiop' and a temp2.txt with text 'asdfghjkl' how can I copy the text of temp1.txt onto temp2.txt without deleting the text it has. I found that I can use the os and shutil modules (https://stackabuse.com/how-to-copy-a-file-in-python/) but they delete the existing text and replace it with the new one. Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the first file with append to end (`'a+'`) and add the second files content:

```
with open("temp1.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write('qwertyuiop')

with open("temp2.txt","w") as f: 
    f.write('asdfghjkl')

# open f1 with append, open f2 as read, append text:
with open ("temp1.txt","a+") as f1, open("temp2.txt") as f2:
    f1.write(f2.read())

print(open("temp1.txt").read())
```

Output:

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjkl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening temp2.txt file in append mode:
`temp2 = open(temp2.txt, 'a'):`
This way you can append text to the file